# SqlServer.Management.Smo events don't last forever

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, smo

Some technical details: 
SQLServer 2012
.NET Framework 4.51
Windows Server 2012
Visual Studio 2013

I'm subscribing to server events to record actions that I do on SQLServer:
`server.Events.SubscribeToEvents()`

Then of course I start the events using: 
`server.Events.StartEvents();`

But after some arbitary time, I notice that the piece of code I have written, stops receiving events. 
It usually happens when I leave the listener overnight.

Is there any timeout mechanism built-in smo that shuts down the subscription?

Thanks!
Adi

Comment: is your sql instance restarting every night at a set time? i know that our asp.net web sites do via IIS, could be a similar thing with SQL

Comment: I'm just testing a feature, so I use the out-of-the-box "AdventureWorks" DB, with no extra stuff.
But you might gave me a lead!

Comment: However, I have just found this error from Server Manager events:

Event notification 'SQLWEP_23A160D2_8468_4C6A_A5AE_0CC505E93BF0' in database 'master' dropped due to send time service broker errors. Check to ensure the conversation handle, service broker contract, and service specified in the event notification are active.

Comment: I'm digging some more, and I found this error in one of the log files: 

Closed event notification conversation endpoint with handle '{44750579-335A-E411-80BC-000C29D17951}', due to the following error: '<?xml version="1.0"?><Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error"><Code>-8470</Code><Description>Remote service has been dropped.</Description></Error>'.

And: 
<Code>-8490</Code><Description>Cannot find the remote service

But I'm not closing anything...

Comment: You might be encountering a timeout on the service broker conversation. Check this: http://rusanu.com/2008/01/04/sqldependencyonchange-callback-timing/

Comment: Well, I use different thread for getting the events. 
So, the thread's job is only to get the messages from DB, and print them...